# Laravel how to make Eloquent relationship to find all data from child_category table with related category & subcategory name?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-datatables

I have three table:

```
categories table fields id, category_name   
subcategories table fields id, category_id, subcategory_name
child_categories table fields id, category_id, subcategory_id, child_category_name
```

I have three model Category, Subcategory,

1) =>category model code

```
class Category extends model {
   public function subcategory(){
      return $this->hasMany(Subcategory::class);
   }

   public function Child_category(){
      return $this->hasMany(Child_category::class);
   }
}
```

2) =>Subcategory model code

```
class Subcategory extends model {
   public function Category(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
   }
}
```

3) =>Child_category model code

```
class Child_category extends model {
   public function Category(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
   }
}
```

how to make Eloquent relationship to  find all data from child_categories table  with related category & subcategory name?

Comment: Please include code that shows how your relationships are set up and what you have already tried.

Comment: I would suggest having a look at nested sets. https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: I add database table fields name, can @jfadich please take a look now?

Comment: @nazmulhaqued There still isn't any Laravel code. Please update the question to include the code that defines the [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: @jfadich can you please check it now?

Answer (score 1):

Once the relationships are defined you can get them by simply calling the property that has the same name as the relation you need.

```
$category = Category::first();
$subcategory = $category->subcategory;
```

If you wanted to get all the categories with all subcategories and child categories in one line you can use the `with()` method to eagerload them efficiently.

```
$categories = Category::with(['subcategory', 'Child_category'])->get();
```

This will fetch all the categories, then fetch all the related subcategories and child categories and associate them appropriately.